# Set of all linear operators is isomorphic to the set of all corresponding transpose of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $\textsf{V}$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field
>   $F$. Show that $\textsf{T}\mapsto \textsf{T}^t$ is an isomorphism of
>   $\mathcal{L}(\textsf{V},\textsf{V})$ onto
>   $\mathcal{L}(\textsf{V}^*,\textsf{V}^*)$.

I have to show that a map from $\mathcal{L}(\textsf{V},\textsf{V})$ to $\mathcal{L}(\textsf{V}^*,\textsf{V}^*)$ defined by $h(\textsf{T}) = \textsf{T}^t$.
And to show $h$ is well defined homomorphism and one-to-one I am having difficulty in showing well defined. 
[image][image]

Comment: Given your comment below, can you please state precisely how $T^t$ is defined in your book?

Comment: I have uploaded the picture

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in V$ and $T\in L(V,V).$ Then, $T^*:V^*\to V^*$ is defined by $\langle T^*x^*,y\rangle=\langle x^*,Ty\rangle.$  If $\langle x^*,Ty\rangle=\langle x^*,T_1y\rangle$ for some other $T_1:V\to V,$ then $\langle x^*,(T_1-T)y\rangle=0.$ This last equality is true for all $x^*\in L(V,V)$ so $(T_1-T)y=0.$ And since this holds for all $y\in V$, it follows that $T_1=T.$

Comment: Itz not about adjoint it is about transpose of linear operator

Comment: They are the same, I think. In general, if $T:V\to W$ is a linear map, then there is an induced map $T^*:W^*\to V^*:x^*\mapsto x^*T$. i.e. it's essentially a pullback. Or am I misreading the question? If so, please let me know and I will delete my answer.